# Testing tool for automatic testing with different combinations?

Tags: java, testing

I have written code for Java, and I need to test this code with all sorts of different combinations. I have tried using the [PICT](http://www.amibugshare.com/pict/help.html) tool, however, it can be used only in Windows and I would also like to test on Linux machines.

Is there any tool in Linux similar to PICT for automatically creating different combinations for which to test code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a JUnit extension from Google, link [here](http://code.google.com/p/jcombinatorial/)
I have not used this specifically, but combinatorial testing is possible with an apt design and algorithm in place.

Comment: Thanks.I think these are coding oriented.I want built-in tool.IS possible?

Comment: Not that I know of, would do some more r&d to understand and comment

Answer (score 0):

- TestNG tests can use [DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) to be tested with various combinations of inputs.
- [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TwoMinuteExample) is an acceptance testing library that could help you do multiple tests too.